# android finish activity contain a webview when press back button

Tags: android, android-webview, back-button

I have an android application in which I have a button.User presses that button then it start an activity that contain a webview.
The problem is in order to finish webview activity when user press back button in the first time,I tried to finish that activity But not working, It went back to history page.I pressed back button several time,webview activity finish.
How can my app finish webview activity when user press button in the first time?

Here my webview activity

```
public class SocialWebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
ProgressDialog mProgress;
public static String url="";
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.social_web_view);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.social_web_view_external);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     // the init state of progress dialog
    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Web", "Loading...");

    // add a WebViewClient for WebView, which actually handles loading data from web
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // load url
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        // when finish loading page
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
            view.clearHistory();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });


    if(!"".equals(SocialWebViewActivity.url)){
        webView.loadUrl(SocialWebViewActivity.url);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: are you testing this on emulator or device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the onKeyDown(param)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) ) {
        webView.clearHistory(); // clear history
        finish(); // finish activity
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work cause it didn't actually clear history.Activity finished when I hit back button 3 times

Comment: try just calling finish. coz it worked on my device i have tested. Tested twice works fine on my device.

Comment: I tested your code on my device with a different url works fine with the above added code.

Comment: @chinh try loading this url http://slashdot.org/ as a sample. It works on my device with your code no changes except with the url mentioned. Only other change is i added the above onKeyDown(param)

Comment: I tested on Galaxy Samsung Y and HKPhone.But seem like something wrong here?Could you please send me your project that you did with that code above(mail:chinhbk88@gmail.com),I really appreciate your help

Comment: @chinh i tested it on samsung galaxy s3 works fine. I tested your code only. There is no problem with the code. Also the code that i have is from google developers guide http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: @chinh if it helps you can upvote the answer and did it work for you? what was it different in your case?

Comment: Your answer right with one activity call another activity.In my case, the problem is I use tab layout which has 3 different activities,1 activity contain a button. When user click that button,it go to another webview activity.Button onclick event: Intent i = new Intent(activityContainButton, SocialWebViewActivity.class);
       activityContainButton.startActivity(i);

Comment: Your answer right with one activity call another web activity.In my case, the problem is I use an ActivityGroup which contains 3 different activities,1 activity contain a button. When user click that button,it go to another webview activity.Button onclick event: Intent i = new Intent(activityContainButton, SocialWebViewActivity.class);
       activityContainButton.startActivity(i); So that, in web view activity didn't come back to activityContainButton?

Comment: @chinh then the problem lies in the way you asked the question. You should have mentioned the same.

Comment: Sorry about lack of the question,I couldn't think that problem so much complex.I tried simple it as possible